# PowerShell module - hiding cmdlets

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am slowly learning the ropes of writing my own PowerShell modules containing business specific cmdlets to interact with an ERP.

A prerequisite for accessing data in the ERP is successfully logging in through the provided SDK/API.

So I have made a Connect-ERP cmdlet for that purpose where logon credentials and various other information is provided. This works fine.

Next, I have a New-Customer cmdlet for - well - creating a new customer in the ERP, but as this cannot be completed without logging in first, I find I have two options.

1. Check if there is an active, successful connection object available. If not, then write a message telling the user to first run the Connect-ERP cmdlet.
2. This is the one I would like to accomplish: Add code to the Connect-ERP cmdlet which enables the subset of cmdlets for working with ERP components; only if the connection is successful.
   (3. There is also a Disconnect-ERP cmdlet, where I would then like to hide said subset of cmdlets)

Is this at all possible?

Comment: This sounds like a scoping question. Have you looked into [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1)?

Comment: I don't think that situationally hiding cmdlets would make for a good user experience (leaving technical feasibility aside), not least because no other modules do that. Your choices are to either report an error, or to implement desired-state logic where `Connect-ERP` is called on demand from other cmdlets that need an open connection.

Comment: Thank you both. I know this isn't common practice for PowerShell, but I remain playful with the idea.